# Not able to fit UIView to the full size of UIViewController when using FreeForm as Simulated Size in XCode 11

Tags: ios, swift

I made a freeform UIViewController of width 1875 and height 667. I am not able to fit the UIView to the full size of the UIViewController. But it is maxed out at 712 * 627. I checked all the similiar stack overflow questions, but i cannot find a solution. Can some one help me with this ?[ScreenShot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxLbm.jpg) [ScreenShot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5RQDj.jpg)

Comment: You should use constraints

Comment: There is only one base view and the max size is 712 * 627. There is no other view to constraint it.

Comment: If i add a second view on it and increase the width and height. It is giving an error saying ambiguous width and height.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your question well enough. I feel like this is just an issue of Xcode. Will the same issue happen if you create a new view controller?

Comment: Yes. The same issue will happen.

Comment: I see you are setting the layout for the view to be `translates mask into constraints` which is not the default option (at least in my Xcode). Can try to select `Autoresizing mask`?

Comment: I have tried that as well, still it is not working. For me the default is Translates Mask into Constraints.

Comment: Okay. I think the problem is from Xcode, if you sill see the expected result when running in simulators or devices, then just ignore it.

Comment: The problem is i need to place some views on this long view but is not able to see the view in the storyboard.

Comment: But you can create your UI without storyboards or xibs, right?

Comment: Yes I can, i am trying to update an old app which uses a freeform view controller for this purpose, this was working fine in older xcodes. I am trying to figure out why freeform view controllers are now limited to a max width of 712.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer to this question. In the Simulated Size select **Freeform** and in the **Simulated Metrics** -> **Size** -> **FormSheet**. Also check the **Content Size** to **Use Preferred Explicit Size**, and fill in the expected Width and Height. In my case width 1875 and height 667. I hope this will help someone looking for the same.